# SwiftUI Rotation Animation off center

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to make a simple dropdown list item in SwiftUI. This is what the code looks like:

```
struct SomeObject: Hashable {
    var title: String = "title"
    var entries: [String] = ["details", "details2", "details3"]
}
```

- 

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var data: [SomeObject] = [SomeObject()]

    var body: some View {
        List(data, id: \.self) { item in
            HStack {
                Text(item.title)
                Spacer()
            }
            ForEach(item.entries, id: \.self) { entry in
                ListItemView(entry)
            }
        }.listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

- 

```
struct ListItemView: View {
    @State var expanded: Bool = false
    @State var rotation: Double = 0
    private let entry: String

    init(_ entry: String) {
        self.entry = entry
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(.black)
        
            HStack {
                Text(entry)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding()
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(expanded ? 180 : 360))
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.3), value: expanded)
            }.padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 6)
        
            if expanded {
                Text("Details")
            }
        
            Divider().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(.black)
        }
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(.init())
            .onTapGesture {
                expanded.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

For some reason when clicking on the list item the animation looks like this:

[image]

How can I make the arrow rotate on its center point without moving up or down at all?

Comment: Have you tried setting alignment to top in HStack?

Comment: @cora yes that doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have there is that the arrow is animated but when the hidden text appears, that vertical expansion is not animated. That contrast between an element animated and another that is not makes the chevron looks like it is not doing it properly. So, try to animate the VStack like this:

```
struct CombineView: View {
    @State var expanded: Bool = false
    @State var rotation: Double = 0
     let entry: String = "Detalle"



    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Divider().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(.black)
            HStack(alignment: .center) {
                Text(entry)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                Spacer()
                Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding()
                    .rotationEffect(.degrees(expanded ? 180 : 360))
                    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.3), value: expanded)
            }.padding(.horizontal)
                .padding(.vertical, 6)
                .background(.green)
        
            if expanded {
                Text("Details")
            }
    
            Divider().frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .overlay(.black)
        }.animation(.linear(duration: 0.3), value: expanded)//Animation added
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            .listRowInsets(.init())
            .onTapGesture {
                expanded.toggle()
            }
    }
```

}

I hope this works for you ;)

Comment: This doesn't do it. It looks okay on the first expansion but after that the animation doesn't play again for some reason. I'd really like a way to keep the chevron still and not move anywhere when the view expands